# GroupByWithSumPipe to sort a list and sum an attribute of grouped items Angular

Tags: json, angular, typescript, group-by, angular-pipe

I use a `GroupBy` pipe to group my data according to a parameter and it works very well, but I would like to add to this pipe a second parameter like this:

```
<li *ngFor="let object of myArray | groupByWithSum:'color':'price'">
    COLOR:{{object.key}} - SUM_PRICE:{{object.sum}}
</li>
```

Allowing the sum of all items grouped according to an object attribute, here the `price`.

**Example:** [StackBlitz HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/group-by-with-sum-pipe?file=app/group-by-with-sum.pipe.ts)

Here is my object list:

```
var myArray = [
    { name: "Apple",    color: "Green",     price: "5,999" },
    { name: "Banana",   color: "Yellow",    price: "6,999" },
    { name: "Grape",    color: "Green",     price: "12,999" },
    { name: "Melon",    color: "Yellow",    price: "10,999" },
    { name: "Orange",   color: "Orange",    price: "3,999" }
];
```

I want to sort this list by color and get the total sum of the `prices` by `color`.

And that's what I'd like to get:

```
[
    {
        key: "Green",
        sum: "18,998‬",
        value: [
            { name: "Apple", color: "Green", price: "5,999" },
            { name: "Grape", color: "Green", price: "12,999" }
        ]
    },
    {
        key: "Yellow",
        sum: "17,998",
        value: [
            { name: "Banana", color: "Yellow", price: "6,999" },
            { name: "Melon",  color: "Yellow", price: "10,999" }
        ]
    },
    {
        key: "Orange",
        sum: "3,999",
        value: [
            { name: "Orange", color: "Orange", price: "3,999" }
        ]
    }
];
```

I started a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/group-by-with-sum-pipe?file=app/group-by-with-sum.pipe.ts) sorting the list by `color`, but I can't make the sum. If anyone would be willing to help me.

**GroupByWithSumPipe:**

```
export class GroupByWithSumPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(collection: object[], property: string, sum: string): object[] {
    // prevents the application from breaking if the array of objects doesn't exist yet
    if(!collection) { return null; }

    const groupedCollection = collection.reduce((previous, current)=> {
      if(!previous[current[property]]) {
          previous[current[property]] = [current];
      } else {
          previous[current[property]].push(current);
      }

      return previous;
    }, {});

    // this will return an array of objects, each object containing a group of objects
    return Object.keys(groupedCollection).map(key => ({ key, value: groupedCollection[key] }));
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your return statement, you can add the sum statement:

```
transform(collection: object[], property: string, sum: string): object[] {
  //...

  return Object.keys(groupedCollection).map(key => ({ 
    key, 
    sum: groupedCollection[key].reduce((a, b) => a + parseInt(b[sum]), 0),
    value: groupedCollection[key]
  }));
}
```

[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/group-by-with-sum-pipe-iukjyo?file=app/group-by-with-sum.pipe.ts)

You are using strings for price though, I've added a `parseInt` to make it work but you better just make these value numbers in your source data

Comment: I have a question, in my program I use rather decimal that can be positive, but also negative.
My problem is that if I have 500 objects to regroup for the sum,
the result of the sum has a large offset because of the decimal that is not taken into account and even with parseFloat ().

Comment: I edited my Stackblitz to use prices like this: (5.999 ...) with parseFloat () and the result is the same.

Comment: @Quentin That's because you use a comma instead of a dot (`"5,999"` vs `"5.999"`). With a comma the `parseFloat("5,999")` returns `5`. Either way, you should use a number, not a string: `5.999`

Comment: Thanks again, I followed your advice and finally changed the data to number and not to String and it works fine.